Execute a jar file from Java Spring-boot Application as a Window Service
I've been trying to launch a JAR file within a Java Spring Boot application as a Windows service. Initially, I attempted to execute the JAR file using a batch file and the Process Builder, but it resulted in the JAR file being run as a Windows service.
Java Code:
private void startJarFile() {
        String currentDirectory = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        String batchFilePath = current_directory + "\\run_live_view.bat";
        try {
            ProcessBuilder processbuider = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/C", batchFilePath);
            processbuider.start();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        }
    }

Window Batch File:
@echo off
cd/d "C:\Program Files\Java Project"
java -jar JavaProject.jar
exit

Is it possible to execute the JavaProject.jar as an application from Java Spring-boot Application as a Window Service?

One way is to use nssm(the non-sucking-service-manager)

Maybe this helps: How to create a windows service from java app

I want to clarify that i have a Java Spring-boot Application that run as service using nssm and i want to start an external jar file, JavaProject.jar. The JavaProject.jar should run as application not a service. Is that possible?

Its not clear - do you mean run the new app for different account to the service?
